# How many HTTP transactions through a connection in Haproxy

Tags: logging, http, haproxy, transaction-log, requests

I want to know how many http transactions occur through a specific connection of Haproxy with a client (frontend).

If I could associate connection (session) id with the frontend's request I would be able to count number of log lines with this id, calculating the rate.

Is it possible to do with Haproxy 1.6?

**EDIT**

The docs state:

> At the moment, logs will not indicate whether requests came from the
>   same session or not. The accept date reported in the logs corresponds
>   to the end of the previous request, and the request time corresponds
>   to the time spent waiting for a new request. The keep-alive request
>   time is still bound to the timeout defined by "timeout
>   http-keep-alive" or "timeout http-request" if not set.

Is it possible to retrieve required data with Lua scripting?